# Update Multiple values at a single time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sample data

```
   APSDEV      clusterData       Stylecolor
     1            0012             3456
     2            0013             4567
```

and Update Query

```
UPDATE <table name> SET  APS_Dev = 1 FROM <table_name> WHERE d.Style_Color = 0012 AND Cluster_ID = 3456  

UPDATE <table name> SET  APS_Dev = 2 FROM <table_name> WHERE d.Style_Color = 0013 AND Cluster_ID = 4567
```

I would like the  update query

```
  UPDATE <table name>

  SET  APS_Dev = (select          
             (SELECT Item  FROM  fn_split(Dataval,':') where idx in (1))
                from @test)                                              
   FROM <table_name>
   WHERE d.Style_Color in (select 
                 (SELECT Item  FROM  fn_split(Dataval,':') where idx in (3))                            
                           from @test)          

    AND Cluster_ID in     (select 
                  (SELECT Item  FROM  fn_split(Dataval,':')where idx in (2)) 
                            from @test)
```

Getting Error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the 
>        subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an 
>        expression.

I understand error is due to APS_Dev "=" symbol .Can any one suggest how to declare values

Comment: The error message cannot be any more clear: you are assigning a column to a subquery which is returning more than one value.  I think the best thing for you to do now would be to post sample data along with the exact output you expect after the update, and the logic.

Comment: there is no way you can do it like that, different where clause, and each of them has different value to be set into the column, means you have to do separated update query

Comment: `SET  APS_Dev = (select` here, the `SELECT` has more than 1 value, it expects one value to set.

Comment: Must say, I find those selects with a select using a UDF quite peculiar. And probably doesn't return only 1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood exactly what your trying to achieve, but if you split your DataVal and push it into a columns of a temp table the you can update your primary table against a multi-conditioned where clause.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (APSDEV INT
                    ,clusterData NVARCHAR(4)
                    ,stylecolor INT
                    )
DECLARE @toUpdate TABLE (Field1 INT
                        ,Field2 INT
                        ,Field3 INT
                        ,APSDEV INT
                        ,clusterData NVARCHAR(4)
                        ,stylecolor INT
                        )
INSERT  INTO @test
VALUES  (1, '0012', 3456),
        (2, '0013', 4567)
SELECT  *
FROM    @test

INSERT  INTO @toUpdate
VALUES  (1, 1, 1, NULL, '0012', 3456),
        (2, 2, 2, NULL, '0013', 4567)

SELECT  *
FROM    @toUpdate

UPDATE  @toUpdate
SET     APSDEV = [@test].APSDEV
FROM    @toUpdate
JOIN    @test ON [@test].clusterData = [@toUpdate].clusterData
                 AND [@test].stylecolor = [@toUpdate].stylecolor

SELECT  *
FROM    @toUpdate
```

If I've missed the point of what your trying to achieve then let me know.

Comment: Thanks, for suggesting my subquery return more than one value like Multiple UPDATE, same column, different values, different WHERE conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
UPDATE T
    SET APS_Dev = [1]
FROM 
    TheTable T
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT * FROM @test
        CROSS APPLY fn_split(Dataval,':') PIVOT (MAX(Item) FOR idx IN ([1],[2],[3])) ) F
        ON Style_Color = [2]
            AND Cluster_ID = [3]
```